# Does the movement of a passenger change the velocity of an aeroplane?

Tags: homework-and-exercises, newtonian-mechanics, momentum, conservation-laws

I encountered a problem in my physics textbook today.

> An aeroplane of total mass of 50,000kg is travelling at a speed of 200m/s. If a passenger of mass 100kg then walks toward the front of the aeroplane at a speed of 2m/s, what change in the speed of the aeroplane does this cause?

It's easy enough to solve with the law of conservation of linear momentum. But my question is *why? How?*

Because as you move forward in the plane, there is no external force on the system. So it shouldn't effect the plane.

p.s- I'm new to this concept and would be grateful for an in depth walkthrough.

Edit:- The answer in the book says that it's supposed to be 4mm/s difference in velocity. No direction stated. Also, by looking at all of the answers you have given me, I think it's safe to say that there is no '*true*' answer. Both interpretations are equally correct

Comment: How does a rocket fly in space? There is no external force acting on the rocket, still it can accelerate or decelerate.

Comment: @Semoi If you do not consider the expelled reaction mass as external then the COM of the rocket and its exhaust does not accelerate.

Comment: @Adrian Howard: Do you feel my comment implied the COM frame? Using your method of "conditioning" it would be wrong to say: Due to gravity an object accelerates with $g\approx 9.81m/s^2$. Do you feel that we have to explicitly state the reference frame, that the object has a mass unequal to zero, friction is omitted, the earth is considered to be spherical, and that the distance of travel is "small" compared to the radius of the earth? Through there is nothing wrong with stating these assumptions, I **personally** feel they are not helpful in understanding the idea.

Comment: @Semoi Your suggestion that a rocket accelerating or decelerating in space does not experience an external force necessarily implies the COM frame -- that's the only frame where that is true (though then it's still not accurate to say it's accelerating). In the frame of the COM of the system not including the expelled propellant, a thrusting rocket in empty space does experience an external force -- the reaction pair to the force it applies to expel the propellant. That's not an unnecessary complication-- that's _why_ it accelerates.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Approach 1:
Consider the plane and the man as a single system. Since there are no external forces acting on them, the center of mass shouldn't accelerate. But if the man starts running to the right and the plane doesn't react to this, the center of mass would go to the right as well. So in order for the center of mass to stay where it is the plane that should accelerate in the opposite direction.

Approach 2:
When you start walking on a plane your feet "rubs" against the floor of the plane, thus pushes it in the opposite direction that you are moving in. As you gain speed in one direction, the plane does in the other.

But here's the thing: When you're trying to stop the reverse happens and as you come to a stop, the plane goes back to its original speed.

**A little more elaboration**

Someone asked for a mathemetical proof for the first approach. So first check out the attached photo.
[image: Acceleration of the center of mass]

As you see their accelerations are opposite. Furthermore note that ap*mp = -am*mm. Left side of the equation is the total force on the plane, whereas the right side is that on the man times -1. These two forces make up an action-reaction pair. Since it is the man pushing against the floor of the plane it makes sense for the plane to push the man back with an equal but opposite force.
So we have also derived Newton’s third law using his second law. By which I mean the man+plane system has no external forces on it, so we asserted that the center of mass doesn’t accelerate.

Another outcome of this result can be understood by realising that the mass of the plane is so much larger than the man such that the ratio mm/mp is almost zero. Thus, even though the plane slows down due to the acceleration of the man, the decrease in its velocity is not large enough to be noticable.

Comment: Could you elaborate on the approach 1? Could you mathematically prove that in order to regain the center of mass, the plane accelerates?

Comment: @juztignoreme I originally intended for this answer to be a brief explanation for those who are less interested in the calculations but here goes my intentions.. If you need further explanation please ask.

Comment: Would it be too much to ask for a further explanation? I'm not quite sure I understand some of your symbols. (Sorry, I'm kinda new to this)

Comment: @juztignoreme how familiar are you with calculus?

Comment: Ummm... Not as much as to 'fully' understand all of this. I understand some, but not all. A short verbal explanation would mostly suffice.

Comment: @juztignoreme If you can point to a specific direction, I can help. But right now I don’t know what to tell you.

Comment: Just explain as would to a 5-year-old who has enough background in physics to understand the newtonian basics but almost no calculus.

Comment: @juztignoreme the first expression is the position of the center of mass. (Xc = bla bla) The formula is if you didn’t notice is a weighted average of the positions of our objects. We multiply each position with the corresponding mass because we want a heavier object to have a greater effect on the center of mass. As our system moves with a constant speed this position Xc increases with a constant rate, such that it always increases the same amount in a certain time interval. Say 500 km per hour. This rate is our velocity...

Comment: @juztignoreme ... Newton’s second law tells us since there are no external forces, the velocity shouldn’t change. But what is the expression for Vc? Remember Xc had two terms one for the plane one for the man. Vc is the total changing rate, so it is the sum of the changing rates of these two terms. So the velocity of the center of mass is the wieghted sum of the velocities of the plane and the man. We said Vc should be constant. Since Vc = weight1 \* Vman + weight2 * Vplane. If the man starts running his speed Vman increases. To balance things out Vplane should decrease and vice versa...

Comment: @juztignoreme Weights 1 and 2 are alpha_m and alpha_p on the picture that I sent. So once again you can see If the weight of plane is much larger than that of man, it can balance my final equation much easier, since a small change in Vp would have a great effect once it is multiplied by weight2.

Comment: Please do not post scans of handwriting. All math on this site is expected to be written using [MathJax](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference).

Answer (score 0):

What would happen if instead you imagine the plane to be no longer in air, but instead it is floating on a large, still bed of water? I use this example so as to have a situation where there is no friction. Now if you are inside the plane and then run forward will the plane begin to move backward?

The answer is obviously no. You are correct in that Newton’s second law applies to external forces. A man inside the plane has no way to exert an external force on the plane.

This particular example considers possible action reaction pairs. Newton’s third law of motion states that “If an object A exerts a force on object B, then object B must exert a force of equal magnitude and opposite direction back on object A“. But here, object A is the mans feet and object B would be the floor of the plane. If the floor then exerts a force on say the planes chassis, that chassis will then push back on the floor etc. so that there is never a resultant force on the plane itself. Of course this would be different if the man got out and ran along the outside (top) roof of the plane.

You asked about conservation of momentum? The law of conservation of momentum can be stated *the total momentum of a system remains constant if the net external force acting on that system remains zero*

And importantly:

*The total momentum of a system is defined as the vector sum of the momenta of all the objects in that system. According to the law of conservation of momentum, the total momentum of a system remains constant as long as the **net external force** on that system is zero. The forces present between the objects inside the system are called internal forces. These **internal forces do not change the total momentum of a system***.

I guess the question that was asked was worded in such a way as to confuse, but the data in that question are red herrings.

Comment: *"The answer is obviously no."* Are you sure about that? I suggest you try the experiment with a raft.

Comment: You totally missed the point. If you are ON a raft, you are no longer a part of the _internal_ system. ON the raft you are indeed applying an external force. In my answer I stated _Of course this would be different if the man got out and ran along the outside (top) roof of the plane_

Comment: Ok, let's put a canvas enclosure on top of the raft. Now the man is in the raft. Run that experiment. You'll find no physically meaningful distinction between 'on' and 'in;' the raft will still move.

Answer (score 0):

Well here's the thing : If you consider the aeroplane as a separate body its velocity would change because friction applied by you on the plane would then be considered as an external force but if you consider yourself and the plane as a system then the net velocity of the centre of mass of the " you and plane" system would not change since the friction force applied by you on the plane would now be considered as an internal force .

Answer (score 0):

You have three main systems in your question - the plane, the passenger and the plane+passenger.

The plane + passenger system can be considered isolated in the example, no external force is acting on it, so its center of mass remains at constant velocity.

The plane itself has an external force acting on it by passengers feet when he/she tries to change his/her state of motion form rest (relative to the plane) to walk, thus the plane will move in the opposite direction to the passenger.

The passenger has an external force acting on him/her by the reaction of the plane and this enables him/her to start walking.

Due to the third Newton law, motions of the plane and the passenger systems are "opposite to each other" and cancel each other out, so that the center of mass of the plane+passenger system will not change its motion.

Perhaps a little confusing might be, that the passenger is geometrically inside the plane, so the name "external" has wrong visual connotation. But when we talk about systems we distinguish internal/external force based on whether it was produced by objects that are considered to be part of the system versus forces between objects in the system and objects that are not considered part of the system and not by geometrical relations.

Answer (score 0):

I'm pretty confident that the problem means for us to consider the plane as a system not including the passenger. In this case, as other answers have pointed out, the passenger is 'external' to the plane system, and therefore any force the passenger exerts on the plane is an external force on the plane system.

Now for the nuts and bolts of the force interactions.

Ignoring several unnecessary complications (e.g. air drag on the passenger), the passenger is acted upon by three forces -- gravity pushing him into the floor of the plane, the normal force from the plane reacting to that gravity, and the static friction between the passenger's feet and the plane floor that actually propels the passenger forward to his/her 2 m/s walk speed. Two of these forces -- the normal force and the friction force -- come from interactions with the plane, and so, by Newton's third law, there are corresponding forces acting on the plane.

The plane, meanwhile, is acted upon by gravity, by lift, and by the reaction forces to the normal and friction forces on the person (ignoring, e.g, drag and thrust). Under the assumption that the airplane maintains level flight, the gravity and normal forces will cancel with lift, and in any event these forces aren't changed by the passenger's acceleration. That leaves the reaction to the friction force, accelerating the airplane backward in response to the person's forward acceleration.

[image: Free body diagrams for the person and the plane as separate systems.]

Thus, as the passenger accelerates forward, the plane accelerates backward, and by the time the passenger has reached his 2 m/s walk, the plane's velocity will have changed accordingly.

By analogy, think about what would happen if you hopped forward off a stationary skateboard. It should come as no surprise that the skateboard would be propelled backward in response.

Now let's briefly look at this in terms of the system containing both plane and passenger. In this system, indeed, there is no net external force, and so *the center of mass of the system* undergoes no change in velocity. However, *the mass distribution of the system does change*; the person accelerates forward, and so the plane must accelerate backward to maintain the center of mass.

Of course, eventually our passenger will walk headlong into the closed and locked door to the cockpit, at which point this will all happen in reverse and the plane will return to its original velocity, while the passenger is directed sternly back to his/her seat.

(As a side note, we are ignoring the competing drag and thrust on the plane that maintain its velocity. On a real plane, passengers moving back and forth just form small perturbations around an equilibrium velocity, the effects of which are quickly damped out.)

Comment: could you show me mathematical proof of this center of mass interpretation? I have deselected this as the answer because mathematical proof could not be given.

Comment: @juztignoreme I'm not really sure what you want me to 'prove.' Your question seems pretty conceptual. Could you describe more specifically what you'd like me to justify?

Comment: Also, sorry if you had some notification spam from deleted messages. I changed my mind about how to approach your comment.

Comment: Oops! Sorry. I misinterpreted your answer. My bad.

Comment: @juztignoreme No worries!